# How to escape underscore in the string query in hibernate and SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

The `_` (underscore) given in the `SQL` query is not honored.

Example :

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE NAME LIKE '%k_p%';
```

This matches and brings many rows apart from rows which contain `k_p`

Could someone please assist on how to achieve this in `SQL` and also in `Hibernate`? Thanks.

Comment: You can specify an [ESCAPE character](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like). For example LIKE '%k|_p%' ESCAPE '|' .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL LIKE query with underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167132/mysql-like-query-with-underscore)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Have you tried escaping it:

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE NAME LIKE '%k\_p%';
```

`\_` instead of just `_`.

Comment: My string had several underscores that I wanted to treat literally, but I also wanted to match `%` somewhere in there, and didn't want to do lots of escaping.  I found I can use `RLIKE` instead of `LIKE` and just use the Regex syntax `.*` instead of `%`, and input the underscores plainly.  I might prefer this in SQL from now on since like JSON, I might prefer Regex as another common tool to use for any situation.

Comment: is there an inbuilt function?

Comment: @Pysis `.*` is implicit. You can substitute `rlike 'k_p'` for `like '%k\_p%'`, and also `k_p$` for `%k_p`, and `^k_p` for `k_p%`.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is quite late but can be solution for other programmers.
You can try

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE NAME LIKE '%k[_]p%';
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, we appreciate your input! Please edit your question and add a short explanation of your code.

Comment: This does not work in MySQL, at least in version 5.5.30.