# MySQL LIKE query with underscore

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table `images`:

```
+----+--------------+
| id |   img_path   |
+----+--------------+
| 1  | abc_1.jpg    |
| 2  | abc_2.jpg    |
| 3  | abcde_1.jpg  |
| 4  | abcde_2.jpg  |
| 5  | abcdef_1.jpg |
+----+--------------+
```

I would like to select the entries that `img_path` starts with `abc_`, so I use the following query:

```
SELECT id FROM images WHERE img_path LIKE 'abc_%'
```

But it returns all 5 rows. How do I only returns `id` = 1 & 2 ( which `img_path` starts with `abc_`) ?

Answer (score 107):

Found out that `_` is a special character. Have to escape with **backslashes**.

```
SELECT id FROM images WHERE img_path LIKE 'abc\_%'
```

which returns 2 rows as expected

Comment: yes, and a more complete answer is that the underscore matches any single char.

Comment: If you're using Rails / ActiveRecord, you need to double escape, like this: `where( "name LIKE ?", "abc\\_%" )`.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter This has nothing to do with Rails but with the programming language used. Ruby seems to support `'abc\_%'`.

Comment: @xehpuk Well, Rails uses Ruby and `'abc\_%'` wasn't working. So if you're saying pure Ruby supports it then Rails/ActiveRecord must be responsible.

Comment: Proper answer is a bit more complicated, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66069453/3027445

Comment: @podarok Isn't that for SQL Server? Are you sure the `[]` additional syntax is necessary for mysql as well? I tried and didn't need it.

Comment: @site80443 ah, I missed a part about MySQL in question. Yes, my link is for SQL Server, haven't tested this with MySQL, though