# MySQL underscore with LIKE Operator

Tags: mysql, sql, escaping

I have an SQL query which matches results using a `LIKE` :

```
_column_name_%
```

This will return results where the column name is:

```
_column_name_1
_column_name_2
```

The end number could be a really high number e.g. 32523, or even 523624366234.

If I use _column_name_%%%%% this would match 32523, but not 523624366234.

How would I get the LIKE to match without typing % repeatedly?

Comment: Your assumption of how `Like` wildcards work is incorrect.  `%` is a wildcard for any number of characters.  You don't have to repeat it at all - one `%` is sufficient.  `Where Column Like '_column_name_%'` is perfectly fine.

Comment: You don't need to type `%` repeatedly. One is enough. It matches zero or more characters

Comment: Can you show me an example, this only returns any row with _column_name_1 but not _column_name_11 for me.

Comment: Just curiosity: are you speaking about columns names or values in a field?

Comment: give the full complete query you are working on

Comment: @bigdaveygeorge Please show *exactly* how you're querying the data as well as some sample data.  What you're describing does not sound possible.

Comment: Sorry this is a column called 'meta_key' and the value is 'column_name_[the number]'

Comment: @bigdaveygeorge `Where meta_key Like 'column_name_%'` should match any size number on the end.  If it is not matching certain columns, you may want to look at those particular records and make sure there aren't any spaces or unprintable characters at the *beginning* of the column.  The lack of the leading `%` in the `Like` will filter out anything that doesn't literally start with `column_name_`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL LIKE query with underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167132/mysql-like-query-with-underscore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Simple select query with the LIKE operator should look like this

**You have to escape the underscore using "\" if you are having any.**

instead of **pretext_%** use **pretext\_%**

```
Select * from mytable where field_1 like 'pretext\_%'
```

This will return pretext_1 as well as pretext_11