# Identical FULLTEXT vs REGEXP vs LIKE searches returning different results

Tags: mysql, database

I have three different MYSQL queries I am attempting to use to search a single column (classlist); the goal is that the column should contain `_10_` but should not contain `_3_` or `_15_` (an example value might be something like `_4_8_10_15_` which would fail given the `_15_`).

I have tried three different approaches and all three give no errors and yet different results:

1) FULLTEXT searching (with the FULLTEXT index enabled on classlist) returned no errors and yet also returned no results.

`SELECT classlist, classcount FROM subgroupstest WHERE MATCH (classlist) AGAINST ('+10 -3 -15' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

2) Simple LIKE clauses returned 516 rows.

`SELECT classlist, classcount FROM subgroupstest WHERE classlist LIKE "%_10_%" AND classlist NOT LIKE "%_3_%" AND classlist NOT LIKE "%_15_%"`

3) A LIKE/REGEXP hybrid returned 1,912 results.  One example it returned that the second approach did not was `_4_10_18_23_`- this is an accurate result, and there are no duplicates in this result so I have to assume the second approach (no less the first!) is missing something somehow.

`SELECT classlist, classcount FROM subgroupstest WHERE classlist LIKE '%_10_%'  AND classlist NOT REGEXP '_3_|_15_'`

At this point I'm left shaking my head and unsure what is going on.  There are always deeper issues I could try to look for, but can someone verify if I'm even doing the REGEXP and/or FULLTEXT approaches correctly?  It looks like what I've seen on Google after the last few hours of reading and mimicking, but it's my first time using either of those.

Comment: See: [MySQL LIKE query with underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167132/mysql-like-query-with-underscore?rq=1)

Comment: one comment: fullttext indexes are subject to minimum (and maximum) word and token lengths, as well as a list of excluded words  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html,   also the underscore character is a wildcard in LIKE unless it's escaped

Comment: Ah! That explains that part.  I replaced the _ bookends with # now (such as `#10`) and replaced the code appropriately; now approaches 2 and 3 are working.

I did realize that the FULLTEXT needed the same things, so I've updated it here (still no results though): `SELECT classlist, classcount FROM subgroupstest WHERE MATCH (classlist) AGAINST ('+#10# -#3# -#15#' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Comment: For FULLTEXT: Try to set [`ft_min_word_len`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) to 1 and use space as delimiter.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I was able to set ft_min_word_len to 1 (double-checked on PMA's variable page), and then I replaced the underscore (and later hashtag) with just plain spaced. They all work now!  I'll update the main post for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexGold don't write the solution in your question. You can post an answer on your question.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Ah, thanks for the heads up - I moved it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, I found a solution.  First, I made the MYSQL entries plain spaces (`4 8 10 15` in the earlier example).

Then the searches work as follow:

`SELECT classlist, classcount FROM subgroupstest WHERE MATCH (classlist) AGAINST ('+10 -3 -15' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

`SELECT classlist, classcount FROM subgroupstest WHERE classlist LIKE "% 10 %" AND classlist NOT LIKE "% 3 %" AND classlist NOT LIKE "% 15 %"`

`SELECT classlist, classcount FROM subgroupstest WHERE classlist LIKE '% 10 %'  AND classlist NOT REGEXP ' 3 | 15 '`

Interestingly, the simple "Like" version was 2-3 times faster than the other two! Fulltext was slightly slower than REGEXP as well.

Comment: this may be obvious (but just in case it's not) `foo LIKE '% 4 %'`  will *not* match a foo value of `'4 8 16'` i.e. when the first entry in the list isn't preceded by a space, and the same with the last entry not followed by a space... this might call for some special "guard" characters at the start and end of the values, e.g. `# 4 8 9 #` to make sure the spaces are there.  Personally, I'd tend to avoid this kind of "search a list stored in a string" design.  But if I had to, I'd use comma separated values  `'4,8,12,16'` and use of FIND_IN_SET()

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set   e.g. with foo = '4,8,10,15` , then ... `WHERE FIND_IN_SET('10',foo) AND NOT FIND_IN_SET('3',foo)` would evaluate to TRUE