# How to use LIKE in a SQL statement to look for a number followed by the "_" character within the contents of a field?

Tags: php, sql

How to use LIKE in a SQL statement to look for a number followed by the "_" character within the contents of a field?

Ex: how to look for **19_**  or  **21_**    ?

I know that _ is a reserved wildcard.... but I would need to use it here as an actual character... THANKS!!

I have a classes table. Each class has a users text field. The text field looks like this (for a record):

19_m~43~2~4-m~45~0~0-m~46~0~0-m~47~0~0-m~48~0~0-m~49~0~0-m~50~0~0-m~51~0~0-t~6~0~0-t~7~0~0-t~8~0~0-t~9~0~0-m~52~0~0-m~53~0~0-m~54~0~0-t~10~0~0-t~11~0~0-t~12~0~0-t~13~0~0|21_m~43~0~0-m~45~0~0-m~46~0~0-m~47~0~0-m~48~0~0-m~49~0~0-m~50~0~0-m~51~0~0-t~6~0~0-t~7~0~0-t~8~0~0-t~9~0~0-m~52~0~0-m~53~0~0-m~54~0~0-t~10~0~0-t~11~0~0-t~12~0~0-t~13~0~0

The user ids are the numbers that have _ after them. In this example, **19_** and **21_**.

What I am trying to do is to

```
select * from the classes table where a certain user (number followed by _)
```

is present in this USERS field.

I tried something like
[...] prepare

```
("SELECT * from classes WHERE USERI LIKE '".$id."\\_%'")
```

but would not get me this record... it returns an empty result.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  It sounds like you want regular expressions, not `LIKE`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL LIKE query with underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167132/mysql-like-query-with-underscore)

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the desired output? Hard to tell what exactly you're looking for

Comment: I edited the question adding more details. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use backslash:

```
SELECT * from classes WHERE USERI LIKE '19\_'
```

Comment: This should look like the answer, but it still doesn't work.. I will edit the question now for more details :) THANKS

Comment: Which database do you use? I'm trying `LIKE '19_%'` in MySQL - it works.

Comment: i use mysql from a server.. don't know the version.. I'll retry

Comment: You're blocked my account. I must collect positive results from my answers but I can't answer to anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know in advance what could be the number you are looking for before the underscore, just use REGEXP.

Example: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE field_whith_number REGEXP '^([0-9])+_';`

Brief explanation of what is happening in REGEXP:

`^` match the start of the line

`([0-9])+` match 1 or more number

`_` match a single underscore

Please note that this is not an ideal solution with very big tables since it will do a table scan.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have my number stored in the $id variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server for the queries, it could be accomplished with something like

```
...
WHERE USERS LIKE TheID + '#_' ESCAPE '#'
```

The `ESCAPE` after `LIKE` designates an escape character which can be used to specify special characters as literals.

Comment: thanks!! I'll give it a try. I've seen this "escape" thing but didn't quite get how to use it. Now you made it clear for me :)